Is IntelliJ IDEA generating a wrong getter method for aField?
I'm moving some old code to Lombok, and found some difference in the name of the generated getter methods in IDEA and Lombok.
For example, a field like:
private String aField;

In IDEA, a getter method will be generated like this (using IntelliJ Default template):
public String getaField() {
    return aField;
}

But in Lombok, @Data will add a getter method named
getAField()

Which one is correct? It's a bug or just a different choice?
I'm using IDEA 2023.1.5 community and Lombok 1.18.24.

I believe JavaBean spec have it defined, but no one care about it, so it is just aesthetic choice now.

IDEA is at fault (no bug though). Where there was room for discussion was on getURL and getUrl but that is meanwhile also straigthened.

Maybe IJ IDEA generated with another brain (it will think deeper). This case, I prefer lombok.

it's lombok, not intellij that does the generation

What Intellij does (you can see it in Generate -> Getter -> ... in top right corner):
#set($name = $StringUtil.capitalizeWithJavaBeanConvention($StringUtil.sanitizeJavaIdentifier($helper.getPropertyName($field, $project))))

That code is here: https://github.com/JetBrains/intellij-community/blob/2247153ca4c2073591785e1854e9a35f1b513010/platform/util/src/com/intellij/openapi/util/text/StringUtil.java#L981
So your case is basically the first thing that happens in that method:
if (s.length() > 1 && Character.isUpperCase(s.charAt(1))) return s;
Someone did it on purpose, that's for sure, so a different choice, not a bug.

I don't think it's a bug.
I don't think it should affect the business logic of the code, but
for me personally I would choose the getAField() method, since in my opinion it's more correct.
If you want, you can make a report to JetBrains, maybe they will comment on it.
Good luck with programming!
